# get data from mysql table as per IST zone

Tags: mysql

I am using GoDaddy webserver of shared hosting.I have a mysql database in which there are 2 columns which contains datatype date.. I am using following sql queries. From query1 I am getting Expired records & from query2 getting ongoing records. Problem is because webserver uses it's local time so as per indian time zone I am not getting accurate records. Is there any way to fix problem in query.

Query1

> SELECT * FROM offers WHERE startDate <= CURRENT_DATE AND endDate <= CURRENT_DATE

Query2

> SELECT * FROM offers WHERE startDate <= CURRENT_DATE AND endDate >= CURRENT_DATE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your values in database are stored in IST then below should work.

Query 1

> SELECT * FROM offers WHERE DATE_ADD(startDate,INTERVAL -330 MINUTE) <=
>   CURRENT_DATE AND DATE_ADD(endDate,INTERVAL -330 MINUTE) <=
>   CURRENT_DATE

Query2

> SELECT * FROM offers WHERE DATE_ADD(startDate,INTERVAL -330 MINUTE) <= CURRENT_DATE AND DATE_ADD(endDate,INTERVAL -330 MINUTE) >=
>   CURRENT_DATE

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the time zones. I assume MySql is using UTC time by default.

```
SELECT * FROM offers WHERE CONVERT_TZ(startDate,'UTC','Asia/Kolkata') <= CURRENT_DATE AND CONVERT_TZ(endDate,'UTC','Asia/Kolkata') <= CURRENT_DATE;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz

You need to check time zone tables.

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.time_zone;
SELECT * FROM mysql.time_zone_name;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html

Mysql uses these tables to convert th time zones. If above tables are empty. You have to fill it.

```
shell> mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo
```

more info here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html

Comment: It seems to be almost worked. But In india current date is 2017/02/11. so according following query it should not show record whre endDate is less then 2017/02/11 but still it fetches record of 2017/02/10 . I used query like this SELECT * FROM offers WHERE CONVERT_TZ(startDate,'UTC','Asia/Kolkata') <= CURRENT_DATE AND CONVERT_TZ(endDate,'UTC','Asia/Kolkata') >= CURRENT_DATE

Comment: what is value of CURRENT_DATE ?

Comment: It's 2017-02-10

Comment: if CURRENT_DATE = "2017-02-10" it will fetch record of  2017/02/10 because you have used `CONVERT_TZ(endDate,'UTC','Asia/Kolkata') >= CURRENT_DATE`  you can change it to `CONVERT_TZ(endDate,'UTC','Asia/Kolkata') > CURRENT_DATE`

Comment: if a row has start date  2017-01-01 and end date  2017-10-10, it will show this record as well

Comment: Start date is - 2017-02-03   &  End Date is - 2017-02-10

Comment: is CURRENT_DATE  according to IST ? Either both (CURRENT_DATE and column date) should be in UTC or IST for correct result. While comparing dates both timezones should be same.

Comment: current_Date not as per UTC. It's server local time.